# Buttons overlapping in menu

Tags: html, css, jsp

I have this input calendar

```html
<t:inputCalendar  id="gdate" value=".."
 renderAsPopup="true" 
 disabled=".. || .. != 0)}"
 popupDateFormat=".."
 renderPopupButtonAsImage="true" 
    rendered=".." >
</t:inputCalendar>
```

If it is disable, the opacity will change to 0.5. When the opacity is 0.5, the buttons will overlap with the dropdown of my menu.

found this thru inspect element

```html
<img class="ui-datepicker-trigger" src="../calendar.png" alt="Disabled" title="Disabled" style="opacity: 0.5; cursor: default;">
```

No overlapping when opacity is 1.

[Please see link for screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yRoP.jpg)

The orange one is the dropdown menu. The button shouldn't overlap with the dropdown menu

Comment: Add some css so that we can reproduce and write the solution

Comment: any relevant CSS regarding this code please?

Comment: done editing. I can't find the css for this one. I would like to add a style to test first.